# How to use react native's platform-specific extensions with typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, metro-bundler

**The problem:**

I have a react native custom hook with platform specific code, which I need to import based on the platform. If I import it like `import useWifi from 'hooks/use-wifi.android';`, everything works fine (on android).

**What I've tried:**

Following rn's instructions for [platform specific code](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions), I have the following file structure

```
...
hooks
  ...
  use-wifi.android.ts
  use-wifi.ios.ts
...
```

However, when I try to import it like `import useWifi from 'hooks/use-wifi';`, typescript type check does not pass, and I get this error in metro:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module `hooks/use-wifi` from `src/screens/home/index.tsx`: hooks/use-wifi could not be found within the project.
```

I've added a `use-wifi.d.ts` file with

```
export * from './use-wifi.android';
export * from './use-wifi.ios';
```

This allows `tsc` to pass, but metro still fails to bundle.

I guess I could have a single `hooks/use-wifi.ts` file and make the code split there, but I'd rather do it this way if possible.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I did what I described in the last paragraph

Comment: my solution creates 2 files `myComponent.tsx` and `myComponent.ios.tsx` and the first is android (without android in the name) and the second file is loaded when the device is ios .... and it works ... if I name the first component as android (`myComponent.android.tsx`) and also .ios ... it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and I was able to fix by adding this config to the `tsconfig.json` inside "compilerOptions"

"moduleSuffixes": [".ios", ".android", ".native", ""],

Comment: Please don't post the exact same answer under multiple questions